# How to change the default language of Komparator in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, internationalization, app-config

I downloaded Komparator4 source [from this page](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=116039). I installed it but there is no option to change the language (the default is *English*).

There is one folder in the package source with **6 idioms** (Italian, Deutsch, etc.). How can I change the default language from English to one of this?

Comment: The problem I had, trying to install Komparator has nothing to do with it, but leave [the link where I posted this issue.](http://askubuntu.com/q/169426/62483)

Answer (score 1):

Set the language in your KDE settings. It is in the 'system settings' under the united nations flag with the title 'locale'. Then restart the application.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I have to tell you that Komparator4 is the only application in this language, so is not a system configuration.